# Finding index of identical elments in unsorted list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, A and B. What I would like to do is if there is a duplicate in A, say at position i and j, then I would like to remove A[j] and B[j] but keep A[i] and B[i]. The order of these points are important so I cannot sort these arrays. Is there any way to do this?

As an example:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]

B = [9, 23, 13, 52, 2, 32, 100, 1]
```

Desired output:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

B = [9, 23, 13, 52, 32, 100, 1]
```

Comment: please give input and output and what have you tried (code)

Comment: @Epsi95 I have not tried anything yet other than a naive loop, but I am having trouble since this approach counts twice and as a result will remove any item with duplicates whereas I still want to keep one. I thought it would be useless to post this, but if it is of interest I can.

Comment: one way to do is convert it to set and convert back to list. set doesn't store duplicate values

Comment: @sittsering Wow such a nice and simple solution! But will this preserve order?

Comment: @APM500 oh, it doesnt.

Comment: @APM500 check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-duplicates-from-list/

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I updated the post with an example.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That was at typo sorry, ultimately it doesn't matter for my specific application but for now I'll go with keeping only the first instance.

Comment: What is the constrain? This can be solved easily with Time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(n) with a `set`. Just iterate ove A, keep the visited elements in a set, if you find any already visited element hust write down the index, at the end remove those indexes. One thing to mention that removing element from list is not constant time, it can be O(n)

Comment: @Epsi95 No constraint on time or space complexity, but the original ordering of the list must be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok to keep the *last* duplicate:

```
[*A], [*B] = zip(*dict(zip(A, B)).items())
```

If we need to keep the *first* duplicate (there's probably a nicer way):

```
[*A], [*B] = zip(*dict(map({}.setdefault, A, zip(A, B))).items())
or
[*A], [*B] = zip(*dict(zip(A, map({}.setdefault, A, B))).items())
```

Another solution also keeping the *first* duplicate, in case your Python is so old that its dicts aren't ordered:

```
AB = zip(A, B)
seen = set()
B = []
A = [seen.add(a) or B.append(b) or a
     for a, b in AB
     if a not in seen]
```

Boring version of that:

```
AB = zip(A, B)
seen = set()
A, B = [], []
for a, b in AB:
    if a not in seen:
        seen.add(a)
        A.append(a)
        B.append(b)
```

Comment: It is not necessary that `dict` will preserve the element order.

Comment: @Epsi95 I've stopped using such old Python versions long ago.

Comment: @Epsi95 Added a set solution just for you :-D

Answer (score 1):

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]

B = [9, 23, 13, 52, 2, 32, 100, 1]

visited = set()
index_to_be_removed = []

for index, e in enumerate(A):
    if e in visited:
        index_to_be_removed.append(index)
    else:
        visited.add(e)
        
for i in index_to_be_removed[::-1]:
    A.pop(i)
    B.pop(i)
    
    
print(A)
print(B)

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# [9, 23, 13, 52, 32, 100, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another approach for the same:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
B = [9, 23, 13, 52, 2, 32, 100, 1]
index_to_remove = []
for i, elem in enumerate(A):
    # If same element exists in rest of the list, get it's index
    if elem in A[i+1:]:
        j = A[i+1:].index(elem)+i+1
        index_to_remove.insert(0,j)
        
for index in index_to_remove:
    A.pop(index)
    B.pop(index)
print (f'A {A}')
print (f'B {B}')
```

Output:

```
A [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
B [9, 23, 13, 52, 32, 100, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly modified approach using 2 loops (as there is no constraint on time and space complexity)

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7]
B = [9, 23, 13, 52, 2, 32, 100, 1,8]

newA= [i for i in A] # cloning A so that we dont disturb A in loop
for idx,val in enumerate(A):
    for i in range(idx+1,len(A)):
        if(val==A[i]):
            newA.pop(i)
            B.pop(i)
print(newA)
print(B)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[9, 23, 13, 52, 32, 100, 8]
```

Comment: Fails for example `A = [1, 1, 1]; B = [1, 2, 3]`.